# How can I get a list of Users that includes their Claims from a UserManager?

Tags: c#, claims

I have a list of Users (from the AspNetUsers table) retrieved with `_userManager.Users.ToList()`, but they don't have Claims (which are stored in AspNetClaims table) initialized. Is there a way to properly initialize the user with their claims?

This is what I have so far (Using my ApplicationUser implementation below):

```
var emails=_userManager.Users.Select(x=>x.Email).ToList();
var users= ?? //somehow get ClaimsPrincipal from emails??
```

ApplicationUser class (implements IdentityUser):

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string LGID { get; } = ""; //claim set in claims table

    public ApplicationUser() { }

    public ApplicationUser(ClaimsIdentity identity)
    {
        IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims;
        foreach (Claim c in claims)
        {
            switch (c.Type)
            {
                case "LGID":
                    LGID = c.Value;
                    break;
       ......
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get your users via: `var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("mail");`

And then do something like this for each user:

`var claims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user.Id);`